# Copy the code text from MS Visual Studio and keeping the source color and formatting

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

I used to copy the text of my C# code in a word document to have a backup of my progress. Previously the color of the codes (blue, black, green) was kept when I paste it in any text editor program (MS word, WordPad ...). Recently it is not so. The format of the text (indentations) is kept but the color unfortunately is just black. That helped me a lot to have previous version of my code on another monitor.
The codes are displayed just normal in Microsoft Visual Studio but the color is lost when I copy and paste it anywhere else.
(I have checked the paste setting of MS word and they are set to keep the formatting of the source. The problem shouldn't be there.)

I use Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2019.

---

**Edit and answer:**

The problem was that although the "cope rich text on copy/cut" option was checked, my code exceeded the maximum character count for this property. It was solved by changing the "Max Length" to a very big number. Default is 10240 and I added three more zeros.

Therefore the path to the solution is:

**Tools --> options --> Text Editor --> Advanced --> Copy rich text on copy/cut (checked) --> Max Length (a very big number)**

[image]

Comment: Open Tools->Options then Text Editor->Advanced and make sure the "Copy rich text on copy/cut" option is checked.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Thank you. I found Text Editor but unfortunately I couldn't find copy/cut option. Generally in options I couldn't find the words "copy" or "rich"

Comment: The problem persists for me. 2022 Edition

Answer (score 4):

You need to check the options "Copy rich text on copy/cut" and "Use accurate classification" in the Text Editor->Advanced settings dialogue within Visual Studio 2019.

[image: Sample screenshot from settings]

Comment: Even though you specifically wanted Visual Studio 2019, I just wanted to add that Visual Studio Code does a much better job at keeping semantic highlighting, even with the above mentioned settings.

Comment: Thank you. My problem as a newbie in Visual Studio is that I can't simply save my script as a .cs file and continue with my previous version of the script. When you save with a new name, it continues with the new name and includes it in the project and mess up everything. In python I would just save a backup .py file and continue with my previous script as it was.

Comment: You should start using a local GIT repository.

Comment: You're completely right. What I do is very unprofessional.

Comment: Still learning, not unprofessional. I'm also still learning after 25+ years of software development. But please accept the answer here on StackOverflow if you find it answered your question.

Comment: Thank you. In fact I'm also "still learning" in Stackoverflow. I thought it's enough to vote up. Now I learned about the accept button and used it for the first time.

Comment: Dear @joakimriedel
I wanted to add that unfortunately I still have this problem. Sometimes it works but sometime it comes back to black and white although the setting is as you mentioned.

Comment: @Iraj are you sure the setting is still set as in the picture above? I just realized that my settings got automatically cleared when updating to VS 2019 16.6 this week. Perhaps your settings have also been cleared?

Comment: @Iraj did it help?

Comment: thank you for your support and sorry for my delayed reply. Unfortunately mine is always like in the image but it still doesn't work. What you suggested seems very logical, I don't know why it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you download Notepad++ you can use that as a backup medium.

Copy and paste your code into Notepad++, select "Language" at the top, hover over "C" and select "C#".

Once this is done, depending on how your Notepad is configured you should have the key functions etc in a different colour.

If you don't, do the following:

Settings --> Style Configurator --> Click on C# --> Click "Default" --> and set "Foreground Colour" to a colour of your choice. In my example I have chosen blue, which will look something like this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I should try it.

Answer (score 0):

Some months back the default action of MSVS is to copy the text with syntax formatting so I didn't have a problem but was a bit miffed when only plain text is copied when I copy too much.

I think there was a recent update where I discovered that only plain text is being copied.

I tried many extensions (Copy as HTML, Syntax Highlighting Pack, Copy with Line Number) to no avail. Google search could not give me the answer.

Then I found by typing "copy" into the MSVS search bar that there is this new option :

Text Editor -> Advanced -> Copy rich text on copy/cut :

Max length : 10240

? Use accurate classification

I have no idea what Use accurate classification means.

Maybe the option was there all along just that I didn't know about it.

Only by google search of "Use accurate classification" could I find this post.

Still no description of what "Use accurate classification" is about.

Anyway happy that it is finally working now.

Comment: Thank you.
I unchecked that check box and nothing seems to change for me. I thought it might be related to indentation, but it wasn't.

Comment: From Vs Forum: “Use Accurate Classification”: Language services typically provide 2 kinds of colorization – quick syntactic colorization and rich but slower semantic colorization (e.g. user types). This way a newly opened file is already colorized based on syntax, but once semantic information becomes available, richer colorization appears. So when this checkbox is checked, Copy/Cut commands would copy accurate, final colors even if calculating those would take more time (a wait dialog will be shown after 2s).